# Dask read_sql_table throws error AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'

Tags: python, oracle, dask

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
sql_engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@environment')
connection = sql_engine.connect()
# works with PANDAS?
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sql_table('table', connection)
```

The above gives expected output.  Now for Dask...

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dd.read_sql_table('table', connection)
```

...which gives...

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 dd.read_sql_table('qsi_run_info_int', connection)#, 'hedis_version_key')
>
> TypeError: read_sql_table() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'index_col'

...and adding column to index on via...

```
dd.read_sql_table('table', connection, 'column_to_index_on')
```

...gives...

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 dd.read_sql_table('qsi_run_info_int', connection, 'hedis_version_key')
>
> ~.conda\envs\test_dask\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\sql.py in
>   read_sql_table(table, uri, index_col, divisions, npartitions, limits,
>   columns, bytes_per_chunk, head_rows, schema, meta, engine_kwargs,
>   **kwargs)
>        98         raise ValueError("Must specify index column to partition on")
>        99     engine_kwargs = {} if engine_kwargs is None else engine_kwargs
>   --> 100     engine = sa.create_engine(uri, **engine_kwargs)
>       101     m = sa.MetaData()
>       102     if isinstance(table, string_types):
>
> ~.conda\envs\test_dask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py
>   in create_engine(*args, **kwargs)
>       433     strategy = kwargs.pop("strategy", default_strategy)
>       434     strategy = strategies.strategies[strategy]
>   --> 435     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>       436 
>       437
>
> ~.conda\envs\test_dask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py
>   in create(self, name_or_url, **kwargs)
>        54         u = url.make_url(name_or_url)
>        55 
>   ---> 56         plugins = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs)
>        57 
>        58         u.query.pop("plugin", None)
>
> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute
>   '_instantiate_plugins'

What to try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `read_sql_table`, as the docstring specifies, should not be a connection object, but the URI to create that object (in your case the "oracle..." string). This is because the sqlalchemy engines are not serialisable nor thread-safe, so the tasks running the queries need to create their own local versions of the engine.