# I have successful connection to oracle database through python using cx_oracle but I couldn't connect to the database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, oracle, sqlalchemy, connection

```
 import cx_Oracle
 import sqlalchemy
 import pandas as pd
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine

 hostname = r'myhost'
 port = '0000'
 sid = 'ssss'
 username = 'myusername'
 password = 'mypass'


 dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(hostname,port,sid) 
 conn = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password=password, dsn=dsn_tns) 
 conn.connect()
 print('Connected to oracle using cx_oracle')
 engine = create_engine(conn, connect_args={ "encoding": "UTF-8", "nencoding": "UTF-8"})
 engine.connect()
 print('Connected to sql alchemy')
```

This code displays an error after it connects to oracle database using cx_oracle it couldnt connect to sqlalchemy

Out Put

> Connected to oracle using cx_oracle Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\Project\Python Script to connect to oracle
> sql\sqlalchemy_connect.py", line 16, in 
> engine = create_engine(conn, connect_args={ "encoding": "UTF-8", "nencoding": "UTF-8"})   File "", line 2, in create_engine
> File
> "C:\Users\mikim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py",
> line 277, in warned
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]   File "C:\Users\mikim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py",
> line 549, in create_engine
> u, plugins, kwargs = u._instantiate_plugins(kwargs) AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Connection' object has no attribute
> '_instantiate_plugins'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dask read\_sql\_table throws error AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute '\_instantiate\_plugins'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452564/dask-read-sql-table-throws-error-attributeerror-connection-object-has-no-attr)

Comment: https://medium.com/gitconnected/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19 shows how you can use the latest cx_Oracle version (now called python-oracledb) with SQLAlchemy in Pandas.    Note Pandas just released support for SQLAlchemy 2, so you might need https://medium.com/oracledevs/using-the-development-branch-of-sqlalchemy-2-0-with-python-oracledb-d6e89090899c

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest versions:

```
python3 -m pip install sqlalchemy pandas oracledb --upgrade
```

Make sure you have SQLAchemy 2 and pandas 2 (for this example - the driver and engine create syntax needed is slightly different in the older versions).  Note that [python-oracledb](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) is the new name for cx_Oracle.

In SQL*Plus, create a table:

```
drop table t purge;
create table t (k number, v varchar2(20));
insert into t (k, v) values (1234, 'neutral');
insert into t (k, v) values (5678, 'alkaline');
commit;
```

Create a file, t.py:

```
import os
import getpass
import platform

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import pandas as pd

un = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
cs = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING")
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle+oracledb://:@',
    connect_args={
        "user": un,
        "password": pw,
        "dsn": cs
    })

query = """select * from t"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(text(query), engine)
print(df)
```

Set your environment:

```
export PYTHON_USERNAME='cj'
export PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING='localhost/freepdb1'
```

Run it:

```
$ python3 t.py
Enter password for cj@localhost/freepdb1: XXXXX
      k         v
0  1234   neutral
1  5678  alkaline
```